# Word or term for contentment, balance, wellness, good health, at home

Tags: single-word-requests, phrase-requests, nouns, adjectives

Looking to uncover a word or term that embodies this spirit, but is not so literal. 
That evokes a sense of “what is it”, what will I discover in the place.

A place to achieve this sense of well-being.

Comment: "Domestic bliss"? "domesticity"? "homeliness"? I'm not entirely sure what you're after: what do you mean "not so literal"? Are you looking for a metaphor for a happy home like a warm fire or a family around a kitchen table?

Comment: Home as place of refuge and rejuvenation on a daily basis. 

“Well Within” might be an example of a not so typical way to describe this feeling

Answer (score -1):

The noun phrase **the spirit of hearth and home** has been used in this sense (*though it originally referred to part of the Roman list of deities ['pantheon']).

> Designing a logo that depicts the design of the home, evoking the
>   sweet spirit of hearth and home from a bygone era.

[[dpdesignagency...1893 house case study](http://dpdesignagency.com/1893-house-case-study/)]

> Today, Zahra stands for fine cuisine infused with the warm spirit of
>   hearth and home.

[[Zahra cafe](http://www.zahra-cafe.com/About_us)]

- Vesta, the spirit of hearth and home, was considered the guardian of the Roman people’s family [[coreknowledge](https://www.coreknowledge.org/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/CKHG-G3-U2-about-roman-deities.pdf)]